# Connection between lim inf of sets and lim inf of sequences

Tags: real-analysis

What is the connection between the lim inf of a sequence of sets, and the lim inf of a sequence of numbers, if there is one?

For a sequence of sets $E_n$,
$$\begin{align*}
\lim \inf E_n :&= E_n \text{eventually}\\
               &= \bigcup_m \bigcap_{n\geq m} E_n
\end{align*}$$
For a sequence of numbers $a_n$, 
$$\begin{align*}
\lim \inf a_n &= \sup_m \inf_{n\geq m} a_n 
\end{align*}$$

Is there a corresponding sequence of numbers for a sequence of sets and vice versa? Or is the nomenclature the same only because the definitions look similar visually?

Comment: If $\chi_n$ is the characteristic function of $E_n$, i.e. $\chi_n(x) = 1$ if $x \in E_n$, $\chi_n(x) = 0$ otherwise, then $\liminf \chi_n$ is the characteristic function of $\liminf E_n$, and analogously for $\limsup$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is clear if you think about what $\sup A_n$ and $\inf A_n$ should mean for sets.

When you order sets by inclusion ($\subseteq$), you can define $\sup$ and $\inf$ the same way as for real numbers.

$\sup$ is the smallest upper bound, so you want to find the smallest set, which contains all $A_n$, which is clearly $\bigcup A_n$.

Similarly, $\inf$ is the greatest lower bound, so you want to find the biggest set contained in all $A_n$, which is clearly $\bigcap A_n$.

Now $\limsup A_n = \inf\limits_n\sup\limits_{n\geq k} A_k=\bigcap\limits_n\bigcup\limits_{n\geq k}A_k$ and $\liminf A_n = \sup\limits_n\inf\limits_{n\geq k} A_k=\bigcup\limits_n\bigcap\limits_{n\geq k}A_k$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\chi_A $ denote the characteristic function of the set $A.$ Then $$\chi_{\liminf_{n\to \infty} A_n } =\liminf_{n\to\infty } \chi_{A_n } .$$